# Why this ambiguity error in function overloading with method inherited both from class and interface?

Tags: java

I made an parent class with name `parent` having a `show()` method in it
and an interface `my` having same default `show()` method with different body. Then i made a child class which inherit interface `my` and implement it.

```
class Parent
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

interface Interface
{
    default void show()
    {
        System.out.println("interface");
    } 
}

class Child extends Parent implements Interface
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Child child = new Child();
         child.show();
    }
}
```

If you run it in jdk 8 you will see the output is `parent` parent string.

The question is shouldn't it be an ambiguity error to extend and inherit both base class and interface that implement the same method?

Comment: where assign c variable (c.show())??

Comment: Why is it ambiguous ?
The concrete class Parent should override the functionality of the default ?
The default should only ever be executed if there is nothing else with the same name.

Comment: Edit the title, removed reduction, fix markdown with code block

Comment: The basic rule for multiple inheritance of implementation defined by Java is that if an identically named member is inherited from both a class and an interface, the class implementation always "wins" (no mater how remote).

Answer (score 1):

When you have a method `show()` in an interface, the class that implements that interface must override it and provide its own implementation. But here it has default implementation.

Here the class `Child` gets the method `show()` from `Parent` via inheritance. So the method in the interface is like overridden in class `Child`.

You should not think `show()` as belonging to class `Parent` but think of it as present in class `Child`

**EDIT:** Even if you cast `child` object to type `Interface`,

```
Interface interface = (Interface)child;
```

`interface.show()` will call the implementation of `show()` in class `Child` which here is the inherited `show()` from `Parent` (thus will print `parent`)

Comment: "You should not think show() as belonging to class parent but think of it as present in class c" - Excellent way of putting it

Answer (score 0):

When you calling `show()` method on Child class object it call the `show()` method of your parent class because when you extends a class which have public method then it also belong to child class.

Since you are implementing the interface and in your class `show()`  is present thus you are  hiding the interface `show()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to understand what is meant by inheriting from a superclass.

In your code, Child inherits Parent. This means that *all* the contents of parent is "moved" to Child. So the child class would be like this

```
class Child implements Interface
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         Child child = new Child();
         child.show();
    }

    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}
```

Note that the child class now has the method called `show`. And of course, will the above code result in an ambiguity? Of course NOT! The `show` method in Child overrides the default implementation in `Interface`!

So next time when you encounter this kind of situation, just think of inheritance as "moving all the stuff in the superclass to the subclass" and you will understand why.

Answer (score 0):

This conforms to the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.3) for a good reason.
Adding the default method to `Interface` should not break the implementation of `Child`.

You will get an ambiguity error if you try to inherit two default methods. See http://www.angelikalanger.com/Lambdas/LambdaTutorial/lambdatutorial_5.html#Ambiguity for how to resolve that.